# Delay processing client data : Treat java socket id as a file id

Tags: java, perl, client-server

I have a java client-server application that works fine . Now i wish to make some changes that i am not sure if its possible . I want to delay proccessing the client data when accept of the server breaks . I would like to wrap all the processing logic after accept breaks into a function that i call whenever i wish to process data and not immediately after the accept breaks . Perl allows this using the sysread function which treats the socket id as a File handler and does the processing. Is it possible in Java ?

What exists :

```
void server_side()
{ 

     // usual server code

     accept() // blocking code waiting for client data 

     ...accept breaks so process data now ..
}
```

What i want :

```
void server_side(){

     // usual servercode

     accept() // blocking for client data

     .. I dont want to process just yet .. Wait !
}

void main() 
{
  .. Usual code ..

   **Ok lets process client data here .**

}
```

In a way `Perl` is beautiful and allows such a thing to happen . In perl you can use the `sysread` command like this

```
    Create socket

       void create()
    {

        .. Usual socket code ..
         $sock = $mainsock->accept();
         ... DONT process here . Will process later in function processing 

    }

void processing()

{

    .. Use sysread to treat socket handler as file . 

    .. Lets read now.

    my $bytes_to_read = 1024;
    my $bytes_read = sysread($sock, $buffer, $bytes_to_read);

    ...

}
```

Can i do this in Java ?

Comment: what does the word "break" mean to you?  Do you just mean "return"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing is forcing you to ever do anything to a socket after you accept it.  You have to hold on to the socket object, obviously, to know where to go for the data (or to send data), but you can wait as long as you want for your application to handle the data, regardless of the language.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/Socket.html

Comment: i dont know but i have this strange habit of complicating stuff . I even thought so far ahead as using a condition variables to achieve this . Thanks for your sane answer . you are correct that i dont need to process it immediately . I have no idea how it stuck into my head that i need to process immediately. Thanks alot.